# Querying 2 Views on a Join - answers on one half being duplicated

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 views one holding inbound calls and the other outbound calls.  I want my query to join the 2 views so that the inbound and outbound stand side by side for each operator (destinationname and originationname).  At the moment my current query duplicates one half of the join, in the example below the inbound.

```
SELECT i.destinationname, i.volumein as inbound, o.volumeout as outbound,
       i.year, i.month
FROM InboundCalls i
     inner join OutboundCalls o
          on i.destinationname = o.originationname
GROUP BY i.year, i.month, i.destinationname, o.volumeout, i.volumein


DestinationName  Inbound   Outbound  Year  Month
Accounts Spare      9         33    2016    8
Accounts Spare      9          9    2016    8
Accounts Spare      9          7    2016    8
Accounts Spare      9         38    2016    8
Accounts Spare     21         33    2016    9
Accounts Spare     21          9    2016    9
Accounts Spare     21          7    2016    9
Accounts Spare     21         38    2016    9
```

The result I am looking for will be similar to the below;

```
DestinationName  Inbound   Outbound  Year  Month
Accounts Spare      84       210    2016    9
Accounts Spare      12        32    2016    11
Accounts Spare      36       103    2016    10
Steve Jones         36        96    2016    8
Wayne Rooney       162       172    2016    8
Alan Shearer         1       216    2016    9
Alan Shearer        74        82    2016    8
```

Please let me know if this needs clarifying.

Comment: What do you mean by one row detailing the calls for that day? Can you post an example of what you want the output to look like? It's unclear what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for wrong results is that you join only on destination name, not on year and month.

First, you need to join not only on `DestinationName` but on the `Year` and `Month` as well. If the views have one row per distinct destination name, year and month, then you can get rid of the `GROUP BY` as well.

Second, you probably need a `FULL JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`, assuming that you want results when there are only Incoming but not Outgoing data (and vice versa) for some month.

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(i.destinationname, o.destinationname) AS DestinationName 
    COALESCE(i.volumein, 0)    AS InBound, 
    COALESCE(o.volumeout, 0)   AS OutBound,
    COALESCE(i.year, o.year)   AS Year, 
    COALESCE(i.month, o.month) AS Month
FROM InboundCalls AS i
     FULL JOIN OutboundCalls AS o
     ON  i.destinationname = o.originationname
     AND i.year = o.year
     AND i.month = o.month ;
```

Comment: Wow, that is exactly what I wanted and taken a week out of my life that I will never get back!  Thanks ever so much.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly you would want the output to be this:

```
DestinationName  Inbound   Outbound  Year  Month
Accounts Spare      9         87    2016    8
```

In which case I think the reason you are getting duplicates is because you are grouping by o.volumeout and i.volumein.

If you want a single row for each month and year then you would group by destinationame, mont and year and then get your totals by using SUM e.g.

```
SELECT i.destinationname, sum(i.volumein) as inbound, sum(o.volumeout) as outbound,
       i.year, i.month
FROM InboundCalls i
     inner join OutboundCalls o
          on i.destinationname = o.originationname
GROUP BY i.year, i.month, i.destinationname
```

Comment: Please explain to OP and future readers what your solution entails. Code only and *Try this* are not encouraged.

Comment: Thanks for your effort in helping Ed, unfortunately this still created duplicates.  Thanks again though